# Javascript onclick executing without click

Tags: jquery

I am attaching onclicks to buttons with the function I want to be called when the event happens. When running the page, it goes ahead and executes the function for onclick without clicking.

```
window.onload=function(){
var recipeCount = 0;
//gets the recipes and puts them in the menu bar #left
//places them in buttons
$.getJSON('recipes.json', function(data) {
       $.each(data.recipe, function(i, f) {
       var yep = "</br> <button type='button' id = '" + f.number + "'>" + f.Name + "</button> </br>";
       $(yep).appendTo("#left");
       recipeCount = recipeCount + 1;


     });//for each recipe

   });//getJSON
//ends recipes to menu
for(var i = 1; i < recipeCount + 1; i++){
    $(i).onclick = clicked(i);
}
$("one").onclick = clicked("one");
};//on load

function clicked(idNum){
    $.getJSON('recipes.json', function(data) {
       $.each(data.recipe, function(i, f) {
       if(idNum == f.number){
        var rec = "</br> <h1> " + f.Name + "</h1> " ;
        $(rec).appendTo("#bigBox");

       }

     });//for each recipe

   });//getJSON
}//clicked
```

Answer (score 2):

You are directly calling that `clicked()` function and causing it to be run, that is why.

The proper syntax is more like:

```
$('#some-element').click(function(event) {
    // inside click event handler
});
```

In other words, you would want something like:

```
$('#some-element').click(function(event) {
    clicked('one');
});
```

If you're looking for raw JavaScript style, then I believe it would be:

```
$('#some-element')[0].onclick = functionName;
```

Answer (score 1):

First `$("one")` is not valid, it should be `$(".one")` if one is a CSS class or `$("#one")` if one is an ID of any element.

Second you should do this like.

```
$("#one").click(function(event) {
      clicked("one");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
clicked(i)   executes the function.
```

You need to just associate the function pointer to it.

```
$(i).onclick = clicked(i);
```

Should be

```
$('#'+ i).on('click' , function() {
     clicked(i);
});
```

But this won't work as you seem to be using the value of **i** in your GETjson.
This is a classic closure problem.

```
for(var i = 1; i < recipeCount + 1; i++){
    $('#'+ i).on('click' , function(num) {
        return function() {
                 clicked(num);
        }
    }(i)  
 );
```

}